# Bug in DSolve when using GeneratedParameters?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

In version 13.3, DSolve without GeneratedParameters option

```
DSolve[D[v1[x1, x2, x3, x4], x1]/x1 + D[v1[x1, x2, x3, x4], x2]/x2 == 0, v1, {x1, x2, x3, x4}]
```

gives the correct result:

{{v1 -> Function[{x1, x2, x3, x4}, C[1][1/2 (-x1^2 + x2^2), x3, x4]]}}

However, with GeneratedParameters option

```
DSolve[D[v1[x1, x2, x3, x4], x1]/x1 + D[v1[x1, x2, x3, x4], x2]/x2 == 0, v1, {x1, x2, x3, x4}, GeneratedParameters -> (Unique["C"] &)]
```

it gives

{{v1 -> Function[{x1, x2, x3, x4}, C26[x3, x4][1/2 (-x1^2 + x2^2)]]}}

instead of C26[1/2 (-x1^2 + x2^2), x3, x4] as expected.

Comment: Note that using `GeneratedParameters -> Unique["C"]` gives the expected result (at least in MMA 13.1 on a Mac.)

Comment: Note that in your example, $c_1$ is actually an arbitrary _function_ and not an arbitrary _constant_. This is because you have a PDE and not ODE.

Comment: The question though, is the result wrong or just different form? i.e. is not `C[1][1/2 (-x1^2 + x2^2),x3,x4]` the same as `C26[1][x3,x4][1/2 (-x1^2 + x2^2)]` ?  Just written differently.  Here `C[1]` as well as `C26[1]` are meant to be functions.

Comment: While the form of the result is not what you expected, the result satisfies the equation, i.e., `eqn /. sol` evaluates to `True`